# Is it possible to use Find with wild cards?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

When making global changes to code and variables Find is a great resource. Is there a way to use Find with wild cards to find and replace any non numerical elements or to find and replace only numbers?

Comment: `ReplaceAll` can be used with Notebook objects. See P. 153 of Notebooks and Documents Manual, http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/NotebooksAndDocuments/  and `NotebookGet` and `NotebookPut`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Excellent resource!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Putting the comment into an answer: [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) can be used with Notebook objects. See P. 153 of Notebooks and Documents Manual and read the documentation to [`NotebookGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookGet.html) and [`NotebookPut`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookPut.html).